# Cannot access browser local storage from add-on in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have stored one array in memory using following code using id.js file:

```
var ids = ["a", "b"];
var obj= {};
var loc = '0';
obj[loc] = ids.toString();
    browser.storage.local.set(obj);
    browser.storage.local.get(loc,function(result){
      console.log(result);
      //console output = {v1:'s1'}
    })
```

on addon i have this one html file as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css"/>  


  </head>

<body>

<button class="download">Download</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and popup.js as:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Console.jsm");

var downloadBtn = document.querySelector('.download');
downloadBtn.addEventListener('click', downloadUser);

function downloadUser() {
    browser.storage.local.get("ids",function(result){
        var filename = "ids.txt";
        var text = result;
        alert(text);
        var pom = document.createElement('a');
        pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
        pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

        if (document.createEvent) {
            var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            event.initEvent('click', true, true);
            pom.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
        else {
            pom.click();
        }

    })
}
```

from popup.js is for getting the data from memory and then downloading it. But nothing is working in it.

here is the manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "AAA",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["id.js", "popup.js"]
    }
  ],

   "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],


    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
     "48": "icons/border-48.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Id",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }  

}
```

Comment: In your `popup.js:1:1` the `Components.utils` is undefined. You don't need the console in order to print to it. Also you have and other errors, check the browser console when you are running your web extension.

Comment: Browser console is empty. can you highlight which part you are saying is wrong.

Comment: I'm also getting: `TypeError: downloadBtn is null  popup.js:2:1`
Also, make sure that your web extension can use the local storage: Verify that the `webextensions.storage.sync.enabled` in the `about:config` is set to true

Comment: `Components.utils.import` is not part of WebExtensions. Remove it, and forget about it. Don't try to use anything connected to it.

Comment: @ChristosPapoulas in about:config there is no such option webextensions.storage.sync.enabled

Comment: @Makyen that i have put for debugging purpose. How can create this addon. downloadUser is not working. it is not able to access the memory

Comment: its showing me `Permission denied to access property "localStorage"` . what could be reason of it. i  have put storage as permission in manifest file.

Comment: Please update the code in the question to actually reflect the code you are using to test. Be explicit *in the question* as to what you see that you are not expecting and what you are expecting to happen. What, *exactly*, was shown in the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (Ctrl-Shift-J, or Cmd-Shift-J on OSX) when you tried to install and use the extension?

Comment: what version of FF are you using? Are you sure that you are using the latest version of 52.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

You set local storage using:

```
var loc = '0';
obj[loc] = ids.toString();
browser.storage.local.set(obj);
```

That means key to `ids` is `0`. You should use `0` as key to get it:

```
browser.storage.local.get({0:""},function(result){
    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
}
```

---

If you want to  use `ids` as key, you should set it by:

```
obj["ids"] = ids.toString();
browser.storage.local.set(obj);
```

And get it by:

```
browser.storage.local.get({ids:""},function(result){
    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
}
```